How to print the Action Input text of langchain agent
I am using agent.run  to execute sql query and want to print  sql query along with final output. for ex-

Entering new SQL Agent Executor chain...
The user is asking for a count of records in dim_claims_tbl. I should use the sql_db_query tool to execute a query that gets the count.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_a;[(129338,)]The result of the query is a tuple with a single value.

I need to print  Action Input: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_a;
Please suggest if the required sql query can be retrieved. or is there any other way to print the query as created by model

Do you want to print the result during the reAct process (because it does run queries during thinking/reAct process as well) or when the reAct ends and the agent has final query to run?
